# Javascript | Sending Special String in GET Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, string

How can I turn around this and actually send this youtube URL without jQuery?

```
var xmlhttp;
// compatible with IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
}

var youtube = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zSVu76AX3I"
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/" + youtube, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-PINGOTHER', 'pingpong');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
xmlhttp.send('<?xml version="1.0"?>');
```

Getting error: VM1666:298 GET http://domain.com/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqHon2ytGcI 404 (Not Found)

Comment: in the sample code you are trying send to: "http://example.com" + youtube
this is equal than: "http://example.comhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zSVu76AX3I". not is bad uri format?

Comment: No, actually I forgot to add it in my example above, but in my real code it exists. i will edit.

Comment: send it as query param value `http://example.com/?url=`+youtube`. No contentType for a GET request ... no idea what the xml is all about

Comment: It did solve it, thanks.